# Group Array of object by year

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I am trying to group an array of objects by year.

For context, I have a horizontal timeline graph (D3js) and need to group overlapping dates by year.

I have the following data:

```
[
  {times: [{color: 'red', year: 2031}]},
  {times: [{color: 'green', year: 2031}]},
  {times: [{color: 'blue', year: 2031}]},
  {times: [{color: 'purple', year: 2045}]},
  {times: [{color: 'orange', year: 2045}]},
]
```

And am trying to get it into the following shape (grouped by year):

```
[
  {times: [
    {color: 'red', year: 2031},
    {color: 'green', year: 2031},
    {color: 'blue', year: 2031}
  ]},
  {times: [
    {color: 'purple', year: 2045},
    {color: 'orange', year: 2045}
  ]}
]
```

I have tried using a few variations with `reduce` but just cannot seem to get the data in the shape I need it:

```
data.reduce((result: any, current: any) => {
  const year = current.times[0].year;

  /* Not entirely sure what to do with 'year' here */
  result.push({ times: current.times[0] });

  return result;
}, [{ times: [{}] }]);
```

**How would I refactor the above to get the desired data shape?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could reduce the array by finding the nested object with the right `year`.

```js
var data = [{ times: [{ color: 'red', year: 2031 }] }, { times: [{ color: 'green', year: 2031 }] }, { times: [{ color: 'blue', year: 2031 }] }, { times: [{ color: 'purple', year: 2045 }] }, { times: [{ color: 'orange', year: 2045 }] }],
    result = data.reduce((r, { times: [data] }) => {
        var temp = r.find(({ times: [{ year }] }) => year === data.year);
        if (temp) temp.times.push(data);
        else r.push({ times: [data] });
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```